# How to activate Dataflow Shuffle service?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to use [Dataflow Shuffle service](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#cloud-dataflow-shuffle) in python environment, but it seems shuffle service is not working, as you can see below.

[image: console output]

I set the SDK version above 2.1, and the region is `us-central1`.
I thought we can activate Dataflow Shuffle service by just adding experiments option, am I missing something?

[image]

Following is the code I tested, you can reproduce the phenomenon.

```
import apache_beam as beam

options = beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions()
gcloud_options = options.view_as(
    beam.options.pipeline_options.GoogleCloudOptions)
gcloud_options.job_name = 'dataflow-shuffle-test'
gcloud_options.project = 'PROJECTID'
gcloud_options.staging_location = 'gs://BUCKET/staging'
gcloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://BUCKET/temp'

# maybe this is the wrong way?
debug_options = options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.DebugOptions)
debug_options.experiments = 'shuffle_mode=service'

worker_options = options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.WorkerOptions)
worker_options.disk_size_gb = 20
worker_options.max_num_workers = 2

options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'

def modify_data2(kvpair):
    return {'name': kvpair[0],
            'sum': sum(kvpair[1])
            }


p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

query = 'SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:usa_names.usa_1910_current]'
(p | 'read' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(project='PROJECTID', 
                                                   use_standard_sql=False, 
                                                   query=query))
   | 'pair' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x['name'], x['number']))
   | "groupby" >> beam.GroupByKey()
   | 'modify' >> beam.Map(modify_data2)
   | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://BUCKET/test.txt', num_shards=1)
 )

p.run()
```

The job finishes successfully, without any errors. Any comment would be helpful!

**EDIT**
Thanks to Sergei's answer, I found my mistake. What I mistook is the experiments option. Set the experiments option as below.

```
# set as list, instead of string.
debug_options.experiments = ['shuffle_mode=service']
```

Also I made a gist to run a simple pipeline with shuffle service, the notebook can be runnable on Datalab.
https://gist.github.com/hayatoy/f6664f965a2519ec406e11235faf75b6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@HayatoY, it should be enough to just specify the experiments flag (--experiments shuffle_mode=service).

The Dataflow Shuffle Service is available with the Python SDK starting with the 2.1 version in the us-central1 and europe-west1 regions.

Can you check if you see the experiments line under the "Pipeline options" pane in the Job Details page in the UI? (see my screenshot)

I just launched a simple wordcount pipeline from the command line and validated that Shuffle was used by it (the metric is 0, but that's normal because the wordcount pipeline uses very little shuffle). As long as the metric is not a "-" you have proof that the Shuffle Service was used.

python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount \
  --project $PROJECT_ID \
  --runner DataflowRunner \
  --staging_location $BUCKET/staging \
  --temp_location $BUCKET/temp \
  --output $BUCKET/output \
  --experiments shuffle_mode=service

[image: screenshot of a python pipeline with shuffle]

Comment: Thank you Sergei, I had to set experiments option as list [“shuffle_mode=service”], instead of string. It worked perfectly and could reduce resource usage!

Comment: very nice. Could you share the final code (with the list), so that other users have a code sample to use in the future.

Comment: I added the fix part and also full code as gist, I hope this would help someone :)