# How to Activate Dataflow Shuffle Service through gcloud CLI

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to activate the Dataflow Shuffle [DS] through gcloud command line interface.

I am using this command:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run ${JOB_NAME_STANDARD} \
   --project=${PROJECT_ID} \
   --region=us-east1 \
   --service-account-email=${SERVICE_ACCOUNT} \
   --gcs-location=${TEMPLATE_PATH}/template \
   --staging-location=${PIPELINE_FOLDER}/staging \
   --parameters "experiments=[shuffle_mode=\"service\"]"
```

The job starts. The Dataflow UI reflects it:

[image: DataFlow UI]

However, the logs showing the error with parsing the value:

```
  Failed to parse SDK pipeline options: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct 
  field sdkPipelineOptions.experiments of type []string
```

What am I doing wrong?

This question is indeed related to an existing question:

[How to activate Dataflow Shuffle service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572389/how-to-activate-dataflow-shuffle-service)

however the original question was covering python API, while my problem is with gcloud CLI.

[DS] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#cloud-dataflow-shuffle

P.S. Update

I have also tried:

[image]
[image]

No luck.

Comment: Try changing `"experiments=[shuffle_mode=\"service\"]"` to `"experiments=shuffle_mode=\"service\""`. Is there a reason that you are escaping quotation marks instead of using single quotes? example `'experiments=shuffle_mode="service"'`

Comment: Tried. Same issue. Using double quotes as this is the script standard - every other option seemed to work correctly.

Comment: You tried both of my suggestions or just the last one?

Comment: Note: Quotes are a shell convention not Dataflow.

Comment: I have tried both suggestions.

Comment: Which version of Apache Beam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way (I know of) to enable shuffle_service for template.

You have two options:
a) Run a job not from template
b) create a template that already has shuffle_service enabled.

The unmarshalling issue is most likely because templates only support fixed amount of parameters and template does not support "experiments" parameter.

----UPD----
I was asked on how to create template with shuffle_service enabled.

Here are sample steps I took.

1. Follow [WordCountTutorial](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven) to create project with pipeline definition.
2. Created template with following command:

   mvn -Pdataflow-runner compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WindowedWordCount -Dexec.args="--project={project-name} --stagingLocation=gs://{staging-location} --inputFile=gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/* --output=gs://{output-location} --runner=DataflowRunner --experiments=shuffle_mode=service --region=us-central1 --templateLocation=gs://{resulting-template-location}"

Note --experiments=shuffle_mode=service argument

3. Invoked template from UI or via command:

   cloud dataflow jobs run {job-name} --project={project-name} --region=us-central1 --gcs-location=gs://{resulting-template-location}

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that shuffle mode defined on the template worked. Thank you. Also appreciate the detailed answer with the examples - kudos on that!